# Strange error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant in VC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

```
// foo.hpp file 
class foo 
    { 
    public: 
      static const int nmConst; 
      int arr[nmConst]; // line 7 
    };  
// foo.cpp file 
    const int foo::nmConst= 5;
```

Compiler VC 2015 return error:

> 1>foo.h(7): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>   1> 1>foo.h(7): failure was caused by non-constant arguments or
>   reference to a non-constant symbol   1> 1>foo.h(7): note: see usage of
>   'nmConst'

Why? nmConst is static constant with value defined in *.cpp file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to use `static const int` member as an array size, but you'll have to define this member within class in your .hpp file like so:

```
class foo
{
public:

    static const int nmConst = 10;
    int arr[nmConst];

};
```

This will work.

**P.S.** About the logic behind it, I believe compiler wants to know size of the array member as soon as it encounters class declaration. If you leave `static const int` member undefined within the class, compiler will understand that you're trying to define variable-length array and report an error (it won't wait to see if you actually defined `nmconst` someplace).